# Database Design - What is the Terminology for these Two methods of storing data and what are the Pros Cons of each

Tags: database, data-structures, database-design

There are many ways to link data when storing them in tables within a database and I am not sure how to refer to these two different methods.

I am also curious to know what pros or cons are associated with each method.  Is one method going to be faster when querying the database?  What would be the reason for creating your database structure using method 1 or method 2 or perhaps it depends on the situation?

**Method 1**

Stores all reference keys in parent record

Stored all RecordIDs back in the primary/parent table. This table stores a reference to each table that stores data relating to it:

```
| PersonID_PK  | AccountID | PhoneID | AddressID | FirstName | LastName | Gender |
| AccountID_PK | Account_Name | CreatedBy | CreatedDate |
| PhoneID_PK   | PhoneNum  | PhoneType |
| AddressID_PK | City | Street | State |
```

**Method 2**

All data relating back to the parent table contains the PK of the parent table. Stored PK in foreign/child tables.

This table as is has no knowlege or constraints against any of the tables that refer back to PersonID_PK.

```
| PersonID_PK  | FirstName | LastName | Gender |  
| AccountID_PK | PersonID_PK | Account_Name | CreatedBy | CreatedDate |
| Phone_PK     | PersonID_PK | PhoneNum | PhoneType |
| Address_PK   | PersonID_PK | City | Street | State |
```

Comment: I think you should think about the relationship between these tables, like does a person need more than one phone or address or account, In method 1 a person can only have one phone since, where as in method 2, if there is another table where these can all be linked, a person could have many accounts phones and addresses

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @MaxCarroll You would think... however at my last company when I was working out of Oracle there were SO many tables that had say a PhoneID that links back to a master phone table and under that PhoneID in a child table are all of the Phone Records for Mobile, Home, Work etc...  So it is not always a one to one or one to many scenario as I've seen it done both ways.  Unless if you think of the Parent Phone record as the one to one which technically it would be.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Reading about Database normalization seems to be the answer to my question.

Comment: Regardless of the chosen setup, ensure you store one information in only one place.  In real life, I have seen phone numbers or addresses entered a couple times for the same user, and since they never respect a strict format, it is hell trying to match accounts and reconcile systems.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? [Why was my "shopping list" question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/266284) [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [Help]

Comment: Yeah the reason I could not discover a direct answer is that there isn't one. These two methods do not have defining names. That is what I discovered.  I feel like they should have names that distinguish each as I've pondered both methods for a few years now.